# Is there a way where i can get information from an Object within an Array of an API with a function so that i can show it on the HTML?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get random info from the API of Jojo's. I want to select specific parts of the array object that I get from the API so that I show only the useful information that it provides from the characters. But I can't manage to get the info of the part from "stand_type" of any item in the array, please someone helps me with this.

My Code so far:

```
async function getCharacter() {
    const number = getRandomNumber();
    var infos = await fetch('https://jojoapi.herokuapp.com/DiamondIsUnbreakable').then(response => response.json());
    console.log("Number = " + number);
    console.log(infos[number])
}
```

Comment: You need this: https://jsfiddle.net/sm41rcxu/ (note that your question is about four completely separate things: **1.** load JSON from an API, **2.** select a random element of an array, **3.** extract info from an object, **4.** create a text/image element; you need to break up your issues into their parts or you will never find existing answers)

Answer (score 0):

infos[number] is accessing the object of result with index is the random number. So you need to access the particular key by passing the key name like

```
infos[number]["stand_type"]
infos[number].stand_type
```

And I hope, that generating a random number function of your gives a number less than the array length. I modified the code a bit and it works as expected(I guess)

```
async function getCharacter() {
    var url = 'https://jojoapi.herokuapp.com/DiamondIsUnbreakable';
    var infos = await fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random()*infos.length);
    console.log("Number = " + number);
    console.log(infos[number]["stand_type"])
}
```

Comment: If it works you can approve the answer and upvote it know!